# ListView SimpleCursorAdapter Update

Tags: android, database, listview, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListActivity with a SimpleCursorAdapter, thus the list view contains data from a database.  If I am looking at the list I want it to update (re-query) itself when new data is put in the database being used by the SimpleCursorAdapter.  Is the best way to do this to set a content observer on the database and call a requery() on the cursor when new content comes in ?

Comment: are you using ContentProvider or database?

Comment: He says "data from a database"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the best way to do this to set a content observer on the database and call a requery() on the cursor when new content comes in?

Yes, when there are changes in the database ContentObserver, you should refresh the cursor by calling `requery()`. Now this method is deprecated though,  just request a new cursor, so you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor arrived.